# Prime numbers from permutation

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, permutations

Let $P(n)$ of a sequence $s(1),s(2),s(3),...$ be obtained by leaving $s(1),...,s(n)$ fixed and reverse-cyclically permuting every $n$ consecutive terms thereafter; apply $P(2)$ to $1,2,3,...$ to get $PS(2)$, then apply $P(3)$ to $PS(2)$ to get $PS(3)$, then apply $P(4)$ to $PS(3)$, etc. The limit of $PS(n)$ is $a(n)$ ([A057063](https://oeis.org/A057063)).

The sequence begins
$$1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 10, 12, 7, 16, 18, 11, 22, 13, 5, 28$$

Some examples:
$$1,2,(4,3),(6,5),(8,7),(10,9),(12,11),(14,13),(16,15),(18,17)$$
$$1,2,4,(6,5,3),(7,10,8),(12,11,9),(13,16,14),(18,17,15)$$
$$1,2,4,6,(3,7,10,5),(12,11,9,8),(16,14,18,13)$$
$$1,2,4,6,3,(10,5,12,11,7),(8,16,14,18,9)$$

I conjecture that $a(n)+1$ is prime if and only if $a(n)=2(n-1)$.

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: I don't think "reverse-cyclically permuting every $n$ consecutive terms thereafter" is clear enough, not to me at least. Would you mind posting as an example, in a comment, $P(3)$ of $s(i)=i$?

Comment: @YaakovBaruch, thank you for comment! Done.

Comment: Well, this is easy after you realize that $a(n)=2(n-1)$ iff the number $a(n)$ was shifted only to the left iff $a(n)-((k-2)\not\equiv 1\pmod k$ for all $k<a(n)/2$. Sorry, will fill out details later if necessary.

Comment: At the OEIS page it seems that an open question is whether any integer can be kicked out to infinity.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, thank you for comment! Please share the details.

Comment: @Yaakov,: but it also seems to be provable...

Comment: When looking at the scatterplot of the sequence it is clear that there are subsequences on other lines. For instance I can numerically spot A131426 as one of the densest lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1. Answer to the question.**

**Claim 1.** $a(n)=2(n-1)$ iff the number $d=a(n)$ moves only leftwards (while it moves).

*Proof.* At each move, every moving number moves either to the right or $1$ left.

The number $d=a(n)$ came to the $n$th position during $P(n-1)$, moving $1$ left. If $d$ moved leftwards through all $P(2),\dots, P(n-1)$, then it started at position $n+(n-2)=2(n-1)$ (so $d=2(n-1)$). Otherwise it shifted leftwards by a smaller distance, so it was smaller than $2(n-1)$. $\quad\square$

**Claim 2.** A number $d$ moves only to the left (while it moves) iff $d+1$ is prime.

*Proof.* While $d$ moves to the left, it appears at position $d-i+2$ before $P(i)$. Then, at $P(i)$, it moves to the right iff $d-i+2>i$ and $d-i+2\equiv 1\pmod i$, that is, if $d\equiv -1\pmod i$ and $d+1\geq 2i$, or in other wirds, $i\mid d+1$ and $(d+1)/i>1$.

So, if $p\leq d/2$ is the least prime divisor of $d+1$, then at $P(p)$ the number $d-p+2=(d+1)-(p-1)>p$ shifts to the right (if it did not shift earier --- in fact, it did not). Otherwise, $d$ is prime, and it cannot shift right. $\quad\square$

The two claims yield the result.

**2. Proof that the resulting arrangement is a permutation.**

We fix a number $d$ and describe how it moves. We aim at proving that it shifts rightwards only finitely many times; this clearly yields that $d$ will eventually stop.

Let $a_n$ denote the position of $d$ before $P(n)$, and put $b_n=a_n+n-1$. Informally speaking, $b_n-1$ denotes a position from which $d$ would come to its current position moving only to the left.

If $d$ moves at $P(n)$, we have $a_{n+1}=a_n-1$ if $a_n\not\equiv 1\pmod n$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n+n-1$ otherwise. Therefore, $b_{n+1}=b_n$ if $n\nmid b_n$, and $b_{n+1}=b_n+n$ otherwise (in the latter case we call $n$ a *crucial* index); we want to show that there are finitely many crucial indices.

Let $n<m$ be two consecutive crucial indices. Put $c_n=b_n/n$; if $c_n=1$, then $b_n=n$, and $d$ has just stopped (and $m$ does not exist). Otherwise, if $c_n>1$, we have $b_{n+1}=n(c_n+1)$, and hence $c_n+1>b_{n+1}/(n+1)\geq b_{n+1}/m=b_m/m=c_m$. Since $c_m$ is an integer, we conclude that $c_m\leq c_n$.

Number all crucial indices as $n_1<n_2<\dots$; put $B_i=b_{n_i}$ and $C_i=c_{n_i}$. Those sequences act as follows:
$$
  C_i=B_i/n_i\leq C_{i-1}; \quad B_{i+1}=B_i+n_i=n_i(C_i+1).
$$
So, while $C_i$ preserves the value $k>1$, we have $B_{i+1}=B_i\cdot \frac{k+1}k$. This may happen only finitely many times if $k>1$, since all the $B_i$ are integers.

Thus, the (non-increasing) sequence $C_i$ cannot preserve any value $k>1$ indefinitely, so it decreases from time to time, and eventually it reaches $1$, as desired.

Comment: Barring mistakes, up to $n=30000$ the sequence of record breaking pairs $(n,a(n))$ with respect to the ratio $n/a(n)$ is this:  $(2,2), (5,3), (14,5), (41,8), (122,14), (365,21), (1094,32), (3281,56), (9842,93), (16403,147), (29525,152)\dots$ and notice that $n_{i+1}=3n_i-1$ **provided we ignore** the second to last pair! No similar regularity seems apparent in the $a(n_i)$ sequence.

Comment: On further thought, the $(16403,147)$ interloper is probably a result of $n/a(n)$ not necessarily being quite the "correct" metric to define the records.

Comment: I've added a proof that the result is a permutation. It would be interesting to analyze whether this proof may show something about the records listed by @YaakovBaruch.

Comment: Very neat, and much simpler than I was expecting! As for the record breakers, I used a much more natural metric: sorted all pairs $(n,a(n))$ by $a(n)$ and printed those with $n$ higher than all preceding ones. I got the same result, including $(16493,147)$. I think one could probably get out of your proof a bound on $n$ as a function of $a(n)$.

Comment: @Notamathematician I was was doing brute computation of $a(n)$ for all $n$ up to a large number, and reached my limit that way. But it's actually much cheaper to compute $n$ for all $a(n)$ up to a much smaller limit, and thus verify your extra terms.

Comment: @Notamathematician. I haven't done it the smart way, so my limit was just $n\le50000$ so up to $217$ in your list. In any case, I wouldn't call this "conjecture", just a verifiable calculation. I could have speculated on a conjecture about record breakers, hadn't it been for $a(16493)=147$. Right now I'm more curious about what $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \big(2\sum_{i\le n} a(i)\big)/n^2$ might be.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: I'd like to suggest that you, or someone, post an edit at OEIS, with a link to your answer.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Already approved

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, today I discovered that A066937 is a permutation of the positive integers. Do you have ideas why is it so? If so, then it would be nice to ask a separate question about it where you could put your answer.

Comment: @Notamathematician In this case, the claim about the permutation goes with no doubt, so I do not think it is necessary (neither I think MO is the best place to collect such proofs). Moreover, the claim is very easy: applying the $k$th operation simultaneously to the permutation of integers (and removing zeroes), you still get a permutation, so the result is surely injective. Moreover, a number $n$ (which exists after any operation) is stable after $k$ exceeds $n$, so it is present in the final state.